# Java org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Failed to set preferences: Unable to read profile preferences file

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I can run this program in Eclipse, but cannot when I export it to runnable jar file

```
public void downloadProcess() throws Exception{
    File dir = new File(getDir(), getStockId()+"-"+getFromYear()+"Q"+getFromQuarter()+"~"+getToYear()+"Q"+getToQuarter());
    dir.mkdirs();
    String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath().toString();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path+"\\geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", dir.toString());
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.enabledCache.state", false);

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
    System.out.println(options);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);//line:87
```

In Eclipse, it works, but in a runnable jar, I get this

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Failed to set preferences: Unable to read profile preferences file Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
>   System info: host: 'LITINSU', ip: '192.168.1.112', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>   remote stacktrace: 
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>       at downloadPDF.DownloadPDF.downloadProcess(DownloadPDF.java:87)
>       at main.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:178)
>       at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at

Comment: Check what the value of `path+"\\geckodriver.exe"` is being passed in as. Your driver may be getting bundled inside the jar which could affect the ability of your code to read it.

Comment: I have checked the value it corrects. And I took out the driver when I export the java project to runnable jar and then take driver back under the folder I created which includes jar and driver. Still have the same Error.

Comment: But if I delete **options** in `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);` it can works. Even though the option cant work